# Forth code formatting guide

Tags: code-formatting, forth

I am trying to teach myself Forth by doing Project Euler exercises. I've looked into several tutorials, but I couldn't find any definitive guide as to how to position keywords / control structures. Emacs `forth-mode` seems to have some idea about how the code should be formatted, but I am not really convinced about what I see :) So, for example, the code below:

```
: euler1
    0 1000 0
    do i dup 3 mod -rot 5 mod -rot -rot * 0=
        if i + then
    loop ;
```

Does it make sense to format it this way? Where'd you put conditions? If there's any kind of style guide / a collection of examples, which, you believe, are properly formatted, could you please refer me to that example?

Comment: I can understand the desire to collect more karma points, but seriously... do you believe the links to PE and Emacs are that much needed? Don't you feel even a little awkward when you change someone's question without adding any useful information / correcting anything? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean formatting in the sense of where the whitespace should go, your example seems pretty reasonable; indentation for loops and words makes the code fairly readable for people more used to languages where indentation or brackets are required.

My style preference would be more like the code below, but I am not sure what you code is doing so I may have arranged it in a way that does not make perfect sense. In general I would put the conditions for a conditional on a new line along with the keyword, and if the condition is complicated I would factor it out into its own word (`add-i?` below).

```
: add-i?
    dup 3 mod -rot 5 mod -rot -rot * 0= ;

: euler1
    0 
    1000 0 do
        i add-i? if 
            i + 
        then
    loop ;
```

It can be a little unintuitive to have the starting keyword of a conditional block or loop at the end of the first line, but I sort of think of it as a visual cue similar to the way Python uses a `:` to enter an indented region (or how Visual Basic uses `Then` (see the second example)), e.g.

```
if true:
    print("True")
```

The `then`s and `loop`s are the equivalents of closing curly brackets or keywords like `End If` in Visual Basic e.g.

```
 If True Then
     MsgBox "True"
 End If
```

(which is a slightly confusing example as the use of Then is different to its use in Forth)

Comment: Hm... thanks for the answer. Here's one thing that I saw in one online guide (although from the terminology used I'd guess it comes form some time in the 80'th / beginning of 90's - they use DOS for operating system and call files "screens"). So, in that tutorial the author puts the semicolon always on the separate line, for example.

Comment: Without wanting to get too philosophical or patronising, the emphasis in the phrase style guide goes on the guide. As far as reasonably modern hints on Forth style go, the GForth documentation is probably quite a good resource. I haven't seen much in the way of prescriptive Forth style guides, I would imagine that some would consider the whitespace frivolous though. The main adage seems to be to factor the code into logical words.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reference. Just one more tiny question :) I see that some times there is space before the closing parenthesis in "word's arguments" and other times isn't. Is there any reason for this asymmetry? Also GForth doesn't seem to do it that way.

Comment: I probably need an example to answer properly but for the most part `(` is just an alternative comment marker, so everything after it is ignored, including a `)` if it be there. In other words I think `(` implicitly goes to the next newline anyway. Assuming that you are referring to the `( x y -- y x )` stack effect annotation thing.

Comment: Yes, so given your example, some write it as `( x y -- y x)` (notice the missing whitespace before the closing paren). That looked odd to me, but I saw it several times.

Comment: I would call that bad style, even if you are using an interpreter that allows it, it breaks the usual rule that everything is space delimited. There might be more to it but it just looks like laziness to me.

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner, please do yourself a favor and thoroughly comment your code, like:

```
1       : euler1        ( -- n )
2               0               ( n )
3               1000 0          ( n HI-limit LO-index )
4               DO              ( n )
5                       I DUP   ( n i i )
6                       3 MOD   ( n i mod3 )
7                       -ROT    ( mod3 n i )
8                       5 MOD   ( mod3 n mod5 )
9                       -ROT    ( mod5 mod3 n )
10                      -ROT    ( n mod5 mod3 )
11                      *       ( n mod5*mod3 )
12                      0=      ( n flag )
13                      IF
14                              i +     ( n+i )
15                      THEN
16              LOOP
17      ;
```

You'll see that:

1. at lines 9,10 -ROT -ROT could be resumed with simple ROT
2. it is not necessary to use ROT -ROT that juggle 3 items on data stack
   and could just simple use SWAP like:  3 MOD SWAP 5 MOD
3. more yet you could avoid stack juggling and write: I 3 MOD I 5 MOD

I would write that:

```
: div?          ( a b -- f  ; b DIVIDES a ? )
        mod 0=
;
: euler1.1      ( -- n )
        0
        1000 0
        DO      ( n )
                I 3 div? I 5 div? OR
                IF
                        I +
                THEN
        LOOP
;
```

Comment: Speaking of beginners... Could you please format that code properly? Indent it 4 spaces and Stackoverflow will keep newlines and spaces. It is "Markdown" that you need here.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the forth written today has C inspired formatting.

The classic, and (I think) clearest way to format Forth is to align corresponding or related things.

When corresponding pieces are aligned the code is easier to walk through and may expose a common factor that can be pulled out into its own word. Here's a snippet from my forth-crypt library.

```
\ RSA Digital Signature ( Notice the spacing )
 : signat (   addr-c # -- s )  djb2a      pub-key N rsa   ;
 : verify ( s addr-c # -- f )  djb2a swap prv-key N rsa = ;
```

It's now easy to see that ( N rsa ) is a factor that could be broken-out into another word if desired.

Another style point is, lookahead/parsing words should be flush to the left and regular postfix words are flush to right like so:

```
: P@REL (         -- PadLast )                      FF CR1! DATA@ REL ;
: P!REL ( PadLast --         )                      FF CR1! DATA! REL ;
```